# Calling REST APIs from .NET

Tags: api, c#, .net

I have written a [tool to get the OAuth JWT Token Bearer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53662/oauth-jwt-token-bearer-flow-returns-invalid-client-credentials/53782#53782) from salesforce but do not know what to do next to get my data.

The examples in salesforce look easy but they are using curl and I do not know hwo to do this in c#
e.g.

> curl https://instance_name.salesforce.com/services/data/v46.0/
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D50000000IehZ!AQcAQH0dMHZfz972Szmpkb58urFRkgeBGsxL_QJWwYMfAbUeeG7c1E6
>   LYUfiDUkWe6H34r1AAwOR8B8fLEz6n04NPGRrq0FM"

Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: Yo can avoid using curl if you are not familiar (I tend to never use it). I would look for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497228/is-there-a-c-sharp-wrapper-available-for-the-salesforce-rest-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unofficial [.NET toolkit](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET) is one option:

> The Force.com Toolkit for .NET provides an easy way for .NET
>   developers to interact with the Lighting Platform APIs using native
>   libraries

Without the toolkit, here's a simple C# method that runs an arbitrary SOQL query

```
public string Query(string soqlQuery, String token, String instance) {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = "https://" + instance + ".salesforce.com/services/data/v46.0/query/?q=" + soqlQuery;
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
                var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
}
```